# After calling Action Method using jquery, Unable to put the response in a defined target <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've **load** button on each row of the table which makes the Ajax call to the ActionMehod "GetAssetCalcert". On receiving a response from the server I used a Bootstrap Popup Modal with defined `<div id=popupModal></div>` inside the ModalBody, so OnComplete the data gets rendered in it (which is basically a _partialPage returned by `GetAssetCalcert()` action Method). Its working fine

**First Approach -** Using ASP helpers

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>@asset.ID</td>
    <td>@asset.name</td>
    <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Load", "GetAssetCalcert", new { id = asset.report_asset_id } , new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "popupModel",
        OnComplete = "ShowPopup",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace                                                           
    }, new
    {
        @class = "btn btn-round btn-primary",
        @id = "loadCalcert"
    })
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS**

```
function ShowPopup() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
    $("#loadCalcert").attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
}
```

**Second Approach -** Using Jquery .ajax()

I wanted to make a similar call to the same ActionMethod but using Jquery so I am trying something like this, the popupModal does show up but the data is not being populated in the target div. what am I doing wrong here?

**HTML**

```
<td><button id="loadCalcert" class="btn btn-round btn-primary"> load</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#MyDatatable button').click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var idVal = tr.children('td:eq(0)').text();

    var options = {};
    options.url = "/SiteReport/GetAssetCalcert";
    options.type = "GET";
    options.data = { id: idVal};
    options.contentType = "application/json";
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.target = "popupModel";   <-- how to refer target div id here
    options.success = ShowPopup();     <-- Modal show up so it means this is working
    $.ajax(options);
});
```

The HTML response from the `$.ajax(options);` call is being received and I can confirm it if log it in console `success: fucntion(data){ console.log('Success!', data}`. It's there. But not being rendered in the target DIV

Plus, could anyone tell me... whilst using jquery, is this the best way to reference a button inside a row of a table, so that you could pass a row ID as a parameter when making Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

for the target you need to put "#popupModel" and you need to remove `options.dataType = "json";` because the response is html :

```
$('#MyDatatable button').click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var idVal = tr.children('td:eq(0)').text();

    var options = {};
    options.url = "/SiteReport/GetAssetCalcert";
    options.type = "GET";
    options.data = { id: idVal};
    options.contentType = "application/json";
    //options.dataType = "json";
    options.target = "#popupModel";   
    options.success = ShowPopup(); working
    $.ajax(options);
});
```

and to reference a button inside a row :

**html**

```
<td><button class="loadCalcert" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" data-id="rowId"> load</button>
```

**javascript**

```
$('.loadCalcert').click(function(){
    var idVal = $(this).data('id');

    var options = {};
    options.url = "/SiteReport/GetAssetCalcert";
    options.type = "GET";
    options.data = { id: idVal};
    options.contentType = "application/json";
    //options.dataType = "json";
    options.target = "#popupModel";   
    options.success = ShowPopup(); working
    $.ajax(options);
});
```

Comment: Ok i've added 'options.target = "#popupModel";' back in, removed `dataType="json" `. still only empty Modal show up.